# MySQL LEFT JOIN Returns duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, duplicates

I'm running a query to find users that have received services from our organization, but I don't want their user id to be duplicated. For instance, I may have user id 1 in the system 5 times, but I only want their id to count as 1 occurrence. Here's my query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total'
FROM services
LEFT JOIN users
ON (services.USR_id = users.USR_id)
LEFT JOIN service_type
ON (services.SRV_type = service_type.TYPE_id)
WHERE services.MGR_orgid = $mgrorgid GROUP BY services.USR_id");
```

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN`. It will return rows that don't receive services, and you'll count them. Use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Counting user_id (as suggested below by Lajos) will take care of that though.  Having said that, I'm not sure I see why service_type is in the query at all.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I could have removed it for the sake of the question, but it's used in some of the results in my later code. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `group by ...`, and change the `count(*)` to `count(distinct usr_id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Lajos Veres. That change didn't work exactly, and I've tried several variations of it in the past, BUT I added COUNT(DISTINCT services.USR_id) and it worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM services s
    WHERE s.USR_id = u.USR_id
    AND s.MGR_orgid = $mgrorgid
)
```

Try this instead. I dropped the portion containing `service_type`, given that you do absolutely nothing with that table in your original query.

Comment: Thanks for the input Willem Renzema.